# What happens if I change attribute "selected" on an <option> element via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-select

What is supposed to happen if I change the attribute "selected" on an `<option>` element via Javascript?

**Example**

HTML

```
<select size="1" id="myselect">
  <option>pepper</option>
  <option selected="selected">salt</option>
</select>
```

Javascript

```
    var selectObj = document.getElementById('myselect');
    selectObj.options[1].removeAttribute('selected');
    selectObj.options[0].setAttribute('selected','selected');
```

[Live example on JSFiddle.net .](http://jsfiddle.net/WfeDQ/)

I could not find any documentation on what this is supposed to do (though it seems to change the selected option in the dropdown box).

I tried it in Firefox, and found that setting the attribute on an `<option>` sometimes selects that option, and sometimes not, while in Chrome it always works. So what is it supposed to do? Is this described in any spec?

*Note:*

I know that I can change the selection via JS using e.g. `option.selected=true/false` or `select.value=<newval>`. So my problem is not to find out how to change the selection; I just want to understand what happens if I manipulate the attribute.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement

Comment: This is fine to generate _HTML_, but I wouldn't rely on this changing the selected value, _attributes_ tend to be initial values and don't always update the live version of the page.

Comment: @vittore: Yes, I found that page, too. However, it says nothing about what it means to *change* the attribute "selected". Hence my question...

Comment: It also work on firefox but it's caching the js file and it looks like it doesn't change. 
I tried what you said on my localhost and it's working the same as chrome

Answer (score 1):

The HTML 5.1 spec says, for the [option](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-option-element) element

> The selectedness of an option element is a boolean state, initially
>   false. ... Whenever an option element's selected attribute is added,
>   its selectedness must be set to true.

So when setAttribute("selected", ...) is called, the content attribute gains the attribute value, and the element's "selectedness" state MAY change. Note though that it says that an option element's selectedness is set to true when the element selected attribute is *added*. Which means that if you call `setAttribute('selected','selected')` on an element that already has the selected attribute, it is not required that selectedness of the element or any other option element changes.

What follows then are the consequences of changing the element's "selectedness".

> The selected IDL attribute, on getting, must return true if the
>   element's selectedness is true, and false otherwise.

(If you're not familiar with the terminology, an "IDL attribute" is what most people think of as a "property". e.g. `opt.selected`)

Then, for the [select](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-select-element) element it says:

> If the multiple attribute is absent, whenever an option element in the
>   select element's list of options has its selectedness set to true, ...
>   the user agent must set the selectedness of all the other option
>   elements in its list of options to false.

and

> The selectedOptions IDL attribute must return an HTMLCollection rooted
>   at the select node, whose filter matches the elements in the list of
>   options that have their selectedness set to true.
>
> The selectedIndex IDL attribute, on getting, must return the index of
>   the first option element in the list of options in tree order that has
>   its selectedness set to true, if any. If there isn't one, then it must
>   return −1.
>
> The value IDL attribute, on getting, must return the value of the
>   first option element in the list of options in tree order that has its
>   selectedness set to true, if any. If there isn't one, then it must
>   return the empty string.

and on submitting the form, during [constructing the form data set](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#constructing-form-data-set):

> If the field element is a select element, then for each option element
>   in the select element's list of options whose selectedness is true and
>   that is not disabled, append an entry to the form data set with the
>   name as the name, the value of the option element as the value, and
>   type as the type.

Does that cover what you need to know?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, it only talks about "IDL attributes", which, as you explain, are what is called "properties" in Javascript. My question was specifically about "HTML attributes" (accessed using getAttribute/setAttribute). So it seems this does not answer my question :-).

Comment: The first paragraph quoted is about the content attribute (getAttribute/setAttribute). Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: @sleske - I've reworded the answer slightly to make it clearer what part relates to the `setAttribute` method.

Comment: Thanks. So essentially the spec only says that "selected" sets the inital value, and that it causes the element to become selected if it is added later. In particular, removing the attribute does not have a defined meaning.

Comment: And BTW, Firefox does not follow the spec: Adding attribute "selected" via JS does select the option, but *only* if the user has not changed the option manually. Once the user has changed the option, setting the attribute does not select the element (using the property/IDL attribute "selected" does work).